# PHP/Apache runs as which user on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, permissions, php, amazon-ec2

I have a PHP script (in `/var/www`) that is supposed to write down the logs of operation in a file `deploy.log` (also in `/var/www`) and perform operations on a file situated in other directories of the system (Like `/home/<user>/repo/my-repo.git` and `/srv/pr`). However, it is not doing so currently. When I change the permission of my log file to `777`, the PHP is able to write it to that file. For obvious reasons, I'm unable to keep the permissions at 777.

I read somewhere that the files you wish to operate on should have the same permissions as the user that runs the PHP files. So how do I find out PHP runs under which user? If that's not the correct approach, how can this be resolved?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.x on Amazon EC2.

I also tried setting `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www` for the entire `www` folder but my PHP script still doesn't write to the log file.

Answer (score 6):

The user that runs apache/php is `www-data`.
Run `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/deploy.log` to make the file editable by the web server.
The other files you want to perform operations on also need to be writable by the webserver.

Comment: Ok that does write on my logs, but is it safe to give ownership of files in /srv and /home to www-data?

Comment: There is no other way if you want those files edited by the webserver. However I would give permitions only to the files who need it in /srv and /home